# XML Parser Asyncronous action

Tags: swift

I'm currently receiving Data in xml format and using the XMLParser to parse the data into something more useful. My Dilemma lies inside my UICollectionView. I am rendering cells that each require a network request in order to retrieve some values associated with the particular cell. The only problem with this is that My UI is completely frozen during this action.  I have tried to tie each relevant Object with its own network request to retrieve data associated with the object, but to no avail. Is there a better way to go about this?

How can I make separate network requests to multiple cells without overloading the UI thread.. Ive already tried `DispatchQueue.global(.background).async { }` and returning to the main thread with `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`  but it seems the XML Parser still performs in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I placed the XMLParser.parser() method inside `DispatchQueue.global(.background).async { }`
and inside `public func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser)` reloaded the collectionView